# Replace with another word on the screen

Tags: neovim, substitute

Sometimes I find it convenient to

1. Search for text I want to replace `/original`
2. Start writing a substitution to replace that `:s/`
3. Use `C-r C-w` to put the current word hovered into the command line `:s/original`

I think some vimrc settings can be changed to combine 1 and 2? I recently switched to neovim and haven't copied all of my plugins and vimrc across yet, but I seem to remember that typing `:s/wo...` would search in the text and show me partial matches, so I could immediately `C-r C-w`.

Anyway, after choosing the word to replace, I want to choose the replacement word *which is a word that appears somewhere else in the file*, without typing that whole word manually into the command line.

Unfortunately, while typing the replacement part in `:s` it seems like no words are highlighted in the file so I can't `C-r C-w`.

For example, in this text I want to replace `original` with `replacement`, without typing all of `replacement`.

```
lorem ipsum replacement dolor
original consectetur original
ullamcorper condimentum metus
```

How could I do it?

Comment: You don't have to type that word twice. The last search pattern is stored in `@/`, so you can do just `/word_to_search` and then `s//replace_with`

Comment: @Matt I would do `/wo<C-r><C-w>` then I would do `:s//re...` what next? so I don't have to type all of `replace_with`?

Comment: If you copy the replacement text to some register (say `0`) before starting the `:s`, you could do `:s/original/\=getreg(0)/`

Comment: The last search pattern in in the register `/`. So you can insert it with `<C-r>/`. Only "better" if your last search was a regex not just a plain word. Regarding replacement: I don't think this is possible, but would be happy when someone proves me wrong.

Comment: I have some thoughts [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20864/10604)—Not exactly a duplicate, but might help